# Bash Script oddity

Tags: bash, x11

What in this code would give this, It is not really an error of sorts but it is driving me crazy...

```
#!/bin/bash 
# This script opens 4 terminal windows.
i="0"

while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
xterm &
i=$[$i+1]


done
exit 0
```

This is what I get when I run this..

```
Ghost abrandt $ ./My4Terminals 
Ghost abrandt $ Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Warning: Warning: Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Tried to connect to session manager, None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

Ghost abrandt $
```

Comment: What runlevel are you running in? Are you running this remotely or locally? If you are running it remotely through ssh, are you using X11 forwarding?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67096/xterm-warning-tried-to-connect-to-session-manager

Comment: I am just on my box as a normal user

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I just need to unset the option for the session manager:

```
 $ unset SESSION_MANAGER
```

Works like a charm now...